# What changes does an object undergo during a cast in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I would like to know what happens to the object when we do a cast. Does the layout of the object gets restructured or does the method table changes or is it only to ensure my assignments don't break during runtime ?

Comment: What kind of cast are you talking about? User defined conversions can do whatever they like. Built in conversions between reference types do nothing except checking if the type fits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None!

All you are doing is "pretending" that it is a different type. Of course, if it doesn't inherit from that type (or is actually an instance of the type when downcasting) the cast fails and you get nothing (null) when using the "as" operator to cast, and explicit (C-Style) cast will throw.

Unless, that is, you are dealing with value types (especially number types). If you do the following:

```
double myDouble = 1.5f;
int myInt = (int)myDouble;
double myOtherDouble = (double)myInt;
```

You will get 1 for myInt and myOtherDouble, because the number is truncated when performing the conversion. Most of the other value types don't even support this kind of casting, because the conversion is not defined.

Comment: If you perform an explicit cast and the cast is invalid you don't get null. An InvalidCastException will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

The honest answer is *it depends*.  Some conversions types just involve boxing and unboxing, which just changes the way the code is interpreted at runtime.  The underlying object doesn't actually change.  This type of casting is involved with casts between, for example, from `string` to `object` (as a `string` *is* an `object`, as is everything in C#).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Alternatively, if there's custom/user-defined cast operators involved, then anything could happen.  The cast could create a completely new object that is a representation of the original that was cast.  An example of this kind of cast would be an `int` to a `string`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473.aspx

Comment: Thank you Marty.. hope u don't mind me addressing you that way..;)

Answer (score 2):

As all others have pointed out a cast by itself doesn't change the object being cast.

That said, there is a point worth making about the ability to overload the behavior of [explicit conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx), which appear at first glance as casts. If a type overloads an explicit conversion operator then it *could* (although it **really shouldn't**) change the object being converted.

```
 public class EvilClass
 {
     public int SomeProperty { get; set; }

     public static explicit operator SomeOtherType(B bObj)
     {
         obj.SomeProperty = -1;

         return SomeOtherType.CreateFromEvilClass(bObj);
     }
 }
```

Then, to the user, this looks like a cast:

```
 EvilClass evilClass = new EvilClass();
 evilClass.SomeProperty = 42;

 SomeOtherType sot = (SomeOtherType)evilClass;   // looks like cast..

 Console.WriteLine(evilClass.SomeProperty);     // Will print -1, not 42
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. A cast changes the logical assumption what a pointer points to.

Nothing in the object does change - all what happens is that a check is done whether the objet is of the assumed type.

If you have A and B : A, and a = new A()

Then basically

var B = (B) a

asks the compiler to check that A is actually a B.

Now, if a is ever created as instance of C (C:A) then - this can and will blow at this point.

Comment: Also you can use [as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) :) i.e `var B= a as B;`

Comment: Yes, you also can user another language. The questin is about C# and CASTS, not other langauge constructs.

Comment: Tom, the as operator is a C# construct. the LOC "var B = (B)a" you had mentioned will throw an error if the cast isn't allowed. I suppose Humpty was trying to explain a graceful cast...:D

Answer (score 1):

If you cast a reference type, nothing happens. It is just a runtime check that the object is actually of the specified type. In some situations - like `Byte` to `Double` - the value will change to match the new data type. Actually it will not change but you will get a new value of the new data type that represents the same value. If it comes to user defined conversions it is up to the implementation what happens.

Comment: That is why I mentioned user defined conversions.

Answer (score 1):

*Usually* nothing happens to the underlying data - it just determines how the code is interacting with the object.

However - *some* "casts" actually do a *conversion*, meaning they change the underlying data of an object.

For example:

```
(double)(int)1.1;
```

converts 1.1 to an integer (which truncates to 1), then converts *back* to a `double`, which in this case would return 1.0.

You can also define [explicit conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx) for reference types:

```
public static explicit operator Celsius(Fahrenheit fahr)
{
    return new Celsius((5.0f / 9.0f) * (fahr.degrees - 32));
}

Fahrenheit fahr = new Fahrenheit(100.0f);
Console.Write("{0} Fahrenheit", fahr.Degrees);
Celsius c = (Celsius)fahr;
```

Note that *technically* the original data didn't change in either case - the cast returns a *new* object with new data.

Comment: +1: I think precise answer is "nothing happens to original object". This is very good explanation about what actually get assigned to the left side of assignment (may or may not be related to original object). There is also one more case of "cast" behavior - un-boxing wrong type  `(string)(object)1` will throw...